# How to delete file with specific name from different directories on multiple drives with exception of one directory?

Tags: batch-file

I need to delete a specific file from different locations at the same time. But I would like to retain the file from a particular directory.

For example: My file name is `ABC.txt` which is present in multiple directories on multiple drives (`C:`, `D:` and `E:`), but I want to keep the file `C:\temp\ABC.txt`.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Show us your current code to do this and maybe we'll have a solution.

Comment: `ren c:\folder\abc.txt c:\folder\abc.txt.bak` and `del c:\abc.txt D:\abc.txt e:\abc.txt /a /s` then `ren c:\folder\abc.txt.bak c:\folder\abc.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple one line batch file to delete `ABC.txt` from every directory on drives `C:`, `D:` and `E:` with the exception of `C:\temp\ABC.txt`:

```
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\ABC.txt" "D:\ABC.txt" "E:\ABC.txt" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do @if /I not "%%I" == "C:\temp\ABC.txt" del /F "%%I"
```

Faster is a batch file with multiple commands:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\ABC.txt" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do if /I not "%%I" == "C:\temp\ABC.txt" del /F "%%I"
del /F /S "D:\ABC.txt" >nul 2>&1
del /F /S "E:\ABC.txt" >nul 2>&1
```

On drive `C:` the command **DIR** is executed by command **FOR** in a separate command process executed in background to find all files with name `ABC.txt` in any directory on this drive with appropriate directory listing permissions. The list of found files output by **DIR** line by line with
file path + file name + file extension is captured by **FOR**.

This file names list is processed line by line by **FOR** with first comparing case-insensitive the name of the current file with full path with the full file name of the file never to delete. If the compared strings are not equal, the current file from list is deleted if that is possible at all according to NTFS permissions and sharing file access permissions.

On the other drives `D:` and `E:` the file `ABC.txt` is deleted directly with command **DEL** from all subdirectories which makes the multi-line solution faster.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>nul`, `2>&1` and `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.